# MVC Contrib Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

I m using MVC Contrib grid in the application , i want to change the grid into master grid with grouping , sorting , paging , filtering , edit and add new record functions.

Can anyone tell me whats the best way to achieve?, like should a use any other grid like jquery etc.?

i want to change the simple grid into master grid.

which grid is good to use with MVC:

- JqGrid
- MVc contrib with datatable.js
- Slick Grid
- Telerik Grid

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Telerik mvc grid as a master grid, and it does support grouping, sorting, paging and most of the fancy stuff. They also have working samples on their site.

Answer (score 2):

Use MVC Grid---http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a lot of extensions for the MVC grid. You could possibly look at the Telerik MVC grid http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx or the jqGrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: Thanks, did u use Datatable java script library with contrib grid ?

Comment: i found JQGrid much interesting